# AG-Grid: Add and remove columns in column groups while maintaining the state of other columns

Tags: ag-grid

I have a table built with AG Grid which needs to display different columns depending on the type of data we give it. This is proving slightly difficult, as I can't find a proper interface in AG Grid which allows you setup new columns *in existing column groups*, and *without* blowing up user-driven changes (hidden columns, resizing, pinning, etc).

The biggest issue is that I can't figure out how to access column group definitions.

```
gridOptions.api.getAllColumns()
```

This function from aggrid does not directly provide column groups, just the child columns. Looping through the columns via this function, they have a parent property, but that does not include the coldef for the column group, which means there isn't even really a way to reconstruct the coldef based on the data you get from it (also, the parent property is private in typescript).

Here is a rough plunker, modified from one of the ag grid documentation examples which illustrates it
https://plnkr.co/edit/C8TrwlkFDg5O5V1RJkng?p=preview

I did try having all the columns present in the table at all times, and hiding them programmatically based on the incoming data, however that creates several issues with the default column show/hide functionality (you can manually show the invalid columns). Using the initial coldefs won't work too well either, since that will discard any modifications the user has made to the columns.

Is there anyone out there who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: sorry, but for me, your description is so shallow and I still not get what exactly you are trying to achieve.